# Perforce multiple branches.

Tags: linux, unix, version-control, perforce

I have a question regarding perforce. I need to  setup a scheme where there are 2 versions, a QA and a Production version. I need to be able to submit code, test the change and push it through to production. The development and production versions will be mostly the same, however there are a few differences, such db host names, include paths, etc... 
I would also like t have the ability to have personal versions that could be tested before they are pushed to the QA.

Yes, I have to use perforce.

Does anyone know how to set something like this up? This will be on *nix based OS. I would like to write either a bash or Perl script to handle this.

Thanks,
Your help is really appreciated.

Comment: Firstly, Perforce is a really good tool. As for your problem more info is needed. Where do you want developers to integrate their personal branch changes to? QA or Production? Can you add a diagram of how you expect it all to work?

Comment: 1)Developer checks out code.
2)Developer submits code to QA.
3)QA Server syncs changes down.
4)developer checks changes on QA Box.
5)developer/or possibly someone else, ok's change, and they go to production.

The QA and Prod are 2 different servers, which might have some slight variasions to them, and I would really like perforce to take care of that. 
For example, I will connect to mysqlserverA in QA, but  mysqlserverB in prod.

Comment: Are the variations hard-coded somewhere or in a config file?

Comment: I try to pull the variations out. some variations must remain hard coded. I currently use a perl one liner to do a search/replace. but Am looking for a more robust method. Also, I am interested in writing a script that handles it. As submitting needs to make a sync on multiple machines., using various service accounts, etc... So I am not using p4v.

Comment: I'm guessing one way to do it would be with perforce triggers, firing scripts when code is submitted to the QA branch (assuming you had separate branches for QA and Prod). I've not used them to actually alter the files for submission, but I *think* it would be possible. - http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/p4sag/06_scripting.html

Answer (score 2):

Ok so Production is the "Final Destination". You'll have a branch from Production to QA such that when you want to submit from QA to Production you'll do a Reverse Integration. Similarly your devs can have personal branches from QA such that to submit to QA they'll do a Reverse Integration.

Submitted changes can be checked easily in Perforce just by double-clicking the Changelist.

Is there something specific you need help with?

Answer (score 0):

I'll just add that you can maintain divergence by integrating (`p4 integ`) and then resolving with the `-ay` (accept yours) option.  That gives you merge credit but doesn't actually copy the changes.  That way you can tell Perforce that you want to ignore certain changes that shouldn't ever really be merged, and then you won't be bothered with them anymore.